# In Process Builder -> Customize the Logic, does short circuit evaluation occur?

Tags: process-builder, boolean, criteria-filter

Suppose I have a process builder for the `Account` object. In my criteria, I've selected "Customize the Logic",

Custom logic: `(1 AND 2 AND 3) OR (4 AND 5)`

Conditions:

```
1- IsPersonAccount :: equals :: true
2- CustomContactTextField__pc :: equals :: myvalue
3- CustomContactTextField__pc :: ischanged :: true
4- CustomCaseLookup__c :: not equal :: null
5- CustomCaseLookup__r.Status :: equal :: Closed
```

Conditions 2 and 3 will both throw an error if condition 1 is not true. Likewise, condition 5 will throw an error if condition 4 is not true.

So my question is, how does short-circuiting work here?

Does salesforce evaluate all 5 conditions and then run through the custom logic? Or does it run through the custom logic first and only check the conditions as needed? Or something else?